# Angular 8 - Create multi-app structure sharing same app module

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

I have this requirement to create 5 apps (Ionic 4/Angular 8) with 90% the same code, but small differences. So what I'm trying to implement is something like the following tree:

```
projects/
    app1/
    app2/
    app3/
    app4/
    main/
```

In the app1, app2 etc. I was planning to have only:

- `global.scss`, so that I change the global styles of the underlying applications just by changing some variables.
- `angular.json` to define the app name and how to build/run
- `tsconfig.json`, where I define in the compilerOptions.paths: `'@main/*': ['../main/src']`, so that I can import anything I want from the main app
- And finally the `main.ts` to use the `AppModule` from the `main` app.

The `main` is a totally functioning app on its own.

Is there a way in Angular 8 to do that and re-use the app from `main` and just change some scss and possibly override some modules if needed?

I've seen tutorials about using the `ng generate lib library` and then *re-use* all the components from there, but that would make me duplicate all the code and that's what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

An angular cli multi-project setup basically can reuse any code from any project. So you create your whole app in your lib, and all you have to duplicatie is your app.module. If you decently modularized your app that's no issue at all.

So yeah;

```
ng generate application <application-name>
```

And

```
ng generate library <library-name>
```

Are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference code in ‘main’ from ‘appN’ so should not be a problem. You can import common TS & scss files.

I reuse in similar way a set of common components across few apps.